# The specified query does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am executing a transaction in Hyperledger with the following settings:

```
namespace com.emastersapp


/**
 * Cashier participant identified by userId
 */
participant Cashier identified by userId {
  o String userId
}
```

queries.qry:

```
query getCashierByUserId {
  description: "Get Cashier by UserId"
  statement:
      SELECT com.emastersapp.Cashier
          WHERE (userId == _$userId)
}
```

Inside the logic.js I have a function that call:

```
 let results = await query('getCashierByUserId', { userId: resource.userId });
```

But when running the transaction I got this error:

```
"Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: The specified query does not exist"
```

Answer (score 0):

from above assume the query is in queries should be in queries.qry file.

Thanks

Comment: if the answer (above) does not satisfy, it looks like your business network has yet to be upgraded to include the new query (ie create a new archive, install it/change the version and upgrade) - see example in Steps Three / Four  here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries for exact steps to follow